# Does the chromecast support rtsp video addresses?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

The title pretty much explained it all. I have a video at rtsp://someaddress.com/videopath
Is the Chromecast capable of understanding that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only http transport is supported.

Comment: Ali is it just https or is there a way to display some content with only http? Or maybe using xhr? Thanks for your help!

Comment: xhr uses http transport, so I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Oh haha wow awesome. I was under the impression it still had to be https. I was receiving the "...this content should also be loaded over HTTPS" when loading directly from http. So I guess I'll try converting over to xhr? Unless there is a direct http route? Thanks!

Comment: XHR can be over http or https, both are http transport. It is preferred if everything is over https but if you don't mind to have some of your assets traverse the internet without any security, that is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help on clearing that up Ali! Really appreciate it!